# View Based Apps, default views and frame positions

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I created a View Based App with Apple's templates.  I added the code to the viewDidLoad method:

```
NSLog(@"origin (x, y): (%f, %f)", self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y);
NSLog(@"frame (w, h): (%f, %f)", self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

My output is:

```
2011-06-05 12:12:02.907 ViewBasedApp[1753:207] origin (x, y): (0.000000, 20.000000)
2011-06-05 12:12:02.908 ViewBasedApp[1753:207] frame (w, h): (320.000000, 460.000000)
```

Why does XCode put the origin at (0, 20) instead of (0,0)?  I did not change any other default settings.

The reason I ask is when I use the Window Based App and add in my own subclass of UIViewController and add it programmatically by doing:

```
SomeViewController *vc = [[SomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeView" bundle:nil];
    self.homeViewController = vc;
    [self.window addSubview:homeViewController.view];
    [vc release];
```

my output is:

```
2011-06-05 12:14:47.405 WhereAmIiPhone[1780:207] origin (x, y): (0.000000, 0.000000)
2011-06-05 12:14:47.405 WhereAmIiPhone[1780:207] frame (w, h): (320.000000, 460.000000)
```

I was wondering why the difference in 20 points for the origin and what I can do to avoid having my view being thrown off by 20 points.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is due to the status bar that is 20px height.

that normal and you don't have to worry about this, just make sure your view are 460 points height.

**Any way**  if you want to hide the status bar you can add:

> Status bar is initially hidden NO

to your info.plist

But be aware that apple asks you to have agood reson for that.

**EDIT**

to lower your view in 20 points try:

```
   mapview.frame = CGRectOffset(mapView.frame,0,20).
```

Comment: Well it seems like my view is already 460 right?  My status bar IS enabled when I run it in the simulator (I also did not set it to be off).  But when I drop in something like a MKMapView, it is off by 20px on the bottom.

Comment: Do you create your MKMapView programmatically  ? is so you can set its frame to: the self.view.bounds

Comment: No I was just dropping it in Interface Builder and it looks like it takes up the whole screen.  Then when I run it, there is 20px of whitespace on the bottom :-\.

Comment: I believe you need to change the y position of the view. you can do it in interfaceBuilder or by setting: mapview.frame = CGRectOffset(mapView.frame,0,20).